# Employee allocation based on ranking: Mathematical Model

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, assignment-problem

Suppose I have three employees and I have to assign three employees based on their ranks. If an employee has rank 1 that means he is best. Say, I have the following table

```
Name      Rank
Joe        3
Allen      1
Bob        2
```

I have make one parameter $p_{e, rank}.$ If I can not assign it based on rank then I have to give some penalty. This is a part of an employee allocation problem.

What I did, I make a binary variable $x_{e, r, rank}$ for Assignment of employees to restaurant $r.$ Then I create another variable $\sum(x_{e, r, rank} \cdot p_{e, rank}).$ I am minimizing this sum and this is my objective function.

My query is, is it correct? Or if there is any alternative way to write it in a mathematical program let me know.

Comment: Minimizing the sum is a good starting point. One disadvantage is that it may penalize a single person or restaurant quite heavily. It is an interesting exercise to maintain some equality.

Answer (score 1):

A) I think you might want to use a multi-level score (something like [our BendableScore](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.6.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#bendableScore)):

- SOFT: maximize rank 1 assignments
- SOFTER: maximize rank 2 assignments
- SOFTEST: maximize rank 3 assignments

Otherwise, three rank 2 assignments can be considered better than one rank 1 assignments (which I presume is not the requirement).

Where it gets more interesting is if your number or ranks is dynamic: One dataset can have 3 ranks, while another could have 3000 ranks. In that case, a [fairness like squaring technique](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/02/03/FormulaForMeasuringUnfairness.html) probably works too, to collapse it into a single score level.

B) If, on the other hand, outweighing is the requirement, just use a single score level (SOFT) with weighting (one weight between every two sequential ranks). In your current implementation: rank 1 is twice rank 2. Rank 2 is 1.5 times rank 3. That's weird. It would be more consistent weighting wise, to use rank 1 (penalty 1), rank 2 (penalty 2), rank 3 (penalty 4), rank 4 (penalty 8) and so forth.

Comment: Can you suggest a formulation if we use consistent weighting, to use rank 1 (penalty 1), rank 2 (penalty 2), rank 3 (penalty 4), rank 4 (penalty 8) and so forth. @Geoffrey

Comment: It depends on the solver of course, but something like `2^(rank - 1)` so `penalize("ranking constraint", SOFT, assignment -> 2^(assignment.getRank() - 1))` should get you those weights.
Basically 2^0  is 1, 2^1 is 2, 2^2 is 4, etc.